# How do I filter a dynamodb scan for a value in a list of objects?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, filterexpression

I have a list of objects in my dynamo db:

```
stuff: [
    {
        who: Me,
        what: Confused,
        when: Always
    },
    {
        who: You,
        what: Has an answer,
        when: Now
    }
]
```

I'm trying to filter on a table.scan() based on the "what" key, so I'd like to return that object.

I'm currently trying

```
results = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('stuff.what').eq('Has an answer')
)
```

But I'm not getting any result.  I'm guessing it's because I'm looking for the 'what' in the root of the 'stuff' and not in each index in the list, but I'm not seeing examples of doing forEach filters like this.  I can only find examples of filtering on multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stuff.what` is how you would access a map type, with object notation. You're trying to access a list which should be done like this:

`stuff[0].what = 'has an answer' and stuff[1].what.....`

I would imagine that's not the logic you want, as you want to search all the objects in the list. I would advise modelling your data as a map.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case.  I don't have control over the type of the data, so I might just have to get creative.  Thank you!